# SQL query joining tables

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

**ProductPermission**

- Id
- ProductId
- PermissionName

**SubscriptionPermission**

- Id
- ProductPermissionId
- Granted
- SubscriptionId

**Subscription**

- Id
- ProductId
- SubscriptionName

The point is that given an specify SubscriptionId i need to display for every ProductPermission. I mean, imagine a Product has 30 permission types and a Subscription for that product has 20 permissions assigned then, what I want is to display the 30 permissions, the column granted can be 0, 1 or NULL.

This is the info that I need:

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
| SubscriptionId | ProductPermissionId | Granted |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Could you help me, please?

PS: if you can improve the title, please do it. I really don´t know how to ask this.

Comment: The title seems good enough - with one caveat. Tags [SQL] shouldn't be placed in titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a driver table of all combos to join back to the data that you have:

```
select allcombos.subscriptionId, allcombos.ProductPermissionId,
       sp.granted
from (select SubscriptionId, ProductPermissionId
      from subscription s cross join ProductPermission pp
     ) allcombos left outer join
     SubscriptoinPermission sp
     on sp.subscriptionId = allcombos.subscriptionId and
        sp.ProductionPermissionId = allcombos.ProductPermissionId
```

You can add a `where` clause to specify the subscriptionid, but you need to prefix it with allcombos:

```
where allcombos.SubscriptionId = <whatever>
```

If you only want it for the subscriptions product, then change the allcombos subquery:

```
select allcombos.subscriptionId, allcombos.ProductPermissionId,
       sp.granted
from (select distinct SubscriptionId, pp2.ProductPermission
      from subscriptionProduct sp join
           ProductPermission pp
           on sp.ProductPermissionId = pp.ProductPermissionId left outer join
           ProductionPermission pp2
           on pp.ProductId = pp2.ProductId
     ) allcombos left outer join
     SubscriptionPermission sp
     on sp.subscriptionId = allcombos.subscriptionId and
        sp.ProductionPermissionId = allcombos.ProductPermissionId
```

That may not be the cleanest change to get all the permissions on the products in a subscription.  It would be nice if you had a SubscriptionProduct table.  But, something like that should work.

Comment: It looks promising however it returns permissions for all the products and not just those for the subscription's product.

Comment: I got it! The problem is the schema is not exactly as I described it (for the usual silly corporate policy) but it is done. I appreciate your help Gordon.